# Implement row number in hibernate hql

Tags: mysql, database, jakarta-ee, hql

I am trying to use a mysql query in my java servlet, but since '@' it is not support in hql (`org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '@'`) I am stuck.
The query is supposed to select every nth (e.g. 10) rows in my table as follow:

```
SELECT ranked.COLUMN_NAME
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        @row := @row +1 AS rownum, COLUMN_NAME
    FROM ( 
        SELECT @row :=0) r, TABLENAME
    ) ranked 
WHERE rownum % 10 = 1
```

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: HQL and SQL are two different languages. If you want to use SQL, don't eecute an HQL query. Execute a native query instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am not sure if you are familiar with j2EE, I believe for using Manager and JPA objects, and connecting to the database(e.g. mysql) we need to use hql. Please let me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, I'm quite familiar with Java EE, JPA and Hibernate. If you use JPA, see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String%29. If you use the Hibernate API, see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#createSQLQuery%28java.lang.String%29. If you think you're forced to use HQL (which you're not), why are you passing a SQL query? How could that possibly work?

Comment: You are right, but my question still holds, how we can transfer the query which I've mentioned in mysql to hql?

Comment: This is not translatable to HQL.